# Unable to understand solr query bf filed

Tags: solr, solr4, solr-query-syntax

I am very much new to solr and working to boost the sore of documents but not able to understand the behavior of `bf`

What does it mean `bf= x^y`

How it works? how the score if going to affect in different values of `x` and `y` in above query?

Is there any specific formula or what??

Answer (score 0):

The bf-parameter is available for the [DisMax Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebf%28BoostFunctions%29Parameter) and stands for "boost function". You can use all [available functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions) in a syntax like

```
product(floatField1, floatField2)
```

the standard example why you should need this bf-parameter is "date boosting". So if you can not sort by date but the ranking should prefere new documents you should use it.

Boosting by field or phrase is more common and the DisMax Parser can do this without "boost function" (via "qf" and "pf"-Parameter).